# GCP Cloud Function HTTP trigger "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error

Tags: python, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a GCP Cloud function with an HTTP trigger. I made a test react frontend that needs to trigger this function with a HTTP request.

Here is the code that makes that request:

```
    async function handleSubmit() {
        const url = 'https://us-central1-{project-id}.cloudfunctions.net/hello-test';
        const data = {name:"Jane"};

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
            body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        await response.json();

    }
```

Here is the cloud function:

```
def hello_http(request):
    # Set CORS headers for preflight requests
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from origin http://localhost:3000 with
        # Authorization header
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST', #GET???
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
        }
        return ('test return value')

    # Set CORS headers for main requests
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    }

    return ('another test return value')
```

Here is the error I get when I run this code from my local react app:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-{PROJECT-ID}.cloudfunctions.net/hello-test' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs,
 set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This cloud function works as expected when I use:

```
curl -X POST HTTP_TRIGGER_ENDPOINT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"name":"Jane"}'
```

Any help with getting this request to work with a data object sent as a POST request and a string returned from the cloud function will solve my problem.

Thank you.

Edit: the result of curl -i -X OPTIONS {url}

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Function-Execution-Id: roz4rhywam83
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 9d52fb9b30e029f32c2a787ad0d006d2;o=1
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 20:03:54 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 15
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
```

Comment: Can you include the headers that are output when you `curl` your endpoint?

Comment: For the failing environment (browser I am presuming) ... can you post the request and response traffic flows in full and in detail.

Comment: I think the headers are in here, not completely sure: ```POST /hello-test HTTP/1.1
> Host: us-central1-{PROJECT ID}.cloudfunctions.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 17
> 
* upload completely sent off: 17 out of 17 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000

```

Comment: this should be the request and response traffic flow: ```Request URL: https://us-central1-{PROJECT -ID}.cloudfunctions.net/hello-test
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 172.217.14.206:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /hello-test
:scheme: https
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
access-control-request-headers: content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/?
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

Comment: or as much of it as would fit haha

Comment: In the OPTIONS, I do not see `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000'`. Also, edit your question and include your comments as formatted data to make it easier to read AND not as comments.

Comment: Run this command and post the output in you question: `curl -i -X OPTIONS REPLACE_WITH_URL`

Comment: Thanks for the tip John, this is my first question post and I would like to format it in the most helpful way possible.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
            body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.text());

        console.log(response)
    }
```

where data is a json object and url is the cloud functions url.

This was the cloud function.

```
def app_run(request):
    # For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see
    # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
    # for more information.

    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  # http://localhost:3000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }



    return ('return value', 200, headers)
```